# what is %s in express node.js

Tags: socket.io

**When I use this code that's give me connected sockets length ,but I couldn't understand how it's work what is "%s".**

```
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
  //console.log(socket);
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log("Connected:  %s sockets connected",connections.length);

socket.on("disconnect",function(data){
  connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket),1);
  console.log("Disconnected: %s sockets disconnected",connections.length);
  console.log("Connected: %s sockets",connections.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for `console.log()` string expansion [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console).  `%s` means to insert a string parameter there from the arguments.  It is modelled after `sprintf()` in C.  The first `%s` will be replaced by the first argument after the string.  So, in:

```
console.log("Connected:  %s sockets connected",connections.length);
```

The `%s` will be replaced with `connections.length`.

Note that `console.log()` is not covered by the ECMAScript specification so extended funtionality like this may be browser-specific.

Comment: thank's i read the documentation and there find the answer of question

Answer (score 0):

It's just %s that represent a String(the return type that you will see in the log).